# How do I increase the count by one on the next page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, increment

I'm creating a quiz app in Flutter, and I'm trying to display the question page, answer page, and question page in that order. I want to display the next question when the page transitions from the answer page to the question page, but I cannot pass the increment value properly. I tried to use Navigator.push() and put the following setsetState((){}) as the argument of the page to be transitioned, but I got an error. Could you give me some advice? Thank you.

answer_page.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../components/next_question_button.dart';
import '../screens/question_page.dart';
import '../quiz_list.dart';

class CorrectAnswerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  CorrectAnswerPage({this.scoreKeeper});

  final List<Icon> scoreKeeper;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'correct',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 100,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Divider(
          color: Colors.grey,
          indent: 16,
          endIndent: 16,
        ),
        Text('EXPLANATION',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey)),
        NextQuestionButton(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => QuestionPage(setState: () {
                          quizList.nextQuestion();
                        })));
          },
        ),
        Row(
          children: scoreKeeper,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

question_page.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../screens/wrong_answer_page.dart';
import '../components/answer_button.dart';
import '../quiz_list.dart';
import 'correct_answer_page.dart';

QuizList quizList = QuizList();

class QuestionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  QuestionPage({@required this.setState});

  final setState;

  //QuestionPage(void nextQuestion);

  // QuestionPage(this.scoreKeeper);
  //
  // List<Icon> scoreKeeper;

  @override
  _QuestionPageState createState() => _QuestionPageState();
}

class _QuestionPageState extends State<QuestionPage> {
  List<Icon> scoreKeeper = [];

  void checkAnswer(String userPickedAnswer) {
    String correctAnswer = quizList.getQuestionAnswer();

    if (userPickedAnswer == correctAnswer) {
      scoreKeeper.add(
        Icon(Icons.circle_outlined, color: Colors.red),
      );
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => CorrectAnswerPage(
                  
                  scoreKeeper: scoreKeeper)));
    } else {
      scoreKeeper.add(
        Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.blue),
      );
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => WrongAnswerPage(
                  
                  scoreKeeper: scoreKeeper)));
    }

    
    setState(() {
      quizList.nextQuestion();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                quizList.getQuestionText(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: AnswerButton(
              userPickedAnswer: 'a',
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  checkAnswer('a');
                });
              }),
        )),

        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: AnswerButton(
              userPickedAnswer: 'b',
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  checkAnswer('b');
                });
              }),
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: AnswerButton(
              userPickedAnswer: 'c',
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  checkAnswer('c');
                });
              }),
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: AnswerButton(
              userPickedAnswer: 'd',
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  checkAnswer('d');
                });
              }),
        )),
        //TODO: Add a Row here as your score keeper
        Row(children: this.scoreKeeper)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QuestionPage(setState: () {
                          quizList.nextQuestion();
                        })));
```

Here you pass a function. With `() {}` you create a function and pass it to the next page.

Simply:

```
QuestionPage(setState: quizList.nextQuestion());
```

Then the nextQuestion will be stored in your `setState` variable.

Start declaring the type of the variables so you won't run into a problem where you try to pass an object but you pass a function and the IDE does not say anything because it expects you to know what you do:

```
final Question setState;
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I tried to solve as you advised and found out nextQuestion() is 'void' and it cannot be assigned on answer_page.dart. I solved this problem as follows. I could not solve it without your comments. Thank you!

What I fixed:
`QuestionPage(setState: quizList);`

What I put:
`final QuizList setState;`